# Is it safe use java for generating UUID primary keys?

Tags: java, mysql, database

For some reason it is need to get `UUID` before storing in database. Class `java.util.UUID` can be used for that. But is it safe to use this generated ids as primary key in database or uuid should be generated by db only?

**Note**
Actual MySql is used, but I do not think that it can affect the question answers.

Comment: Define safe in this case

Comment: Define 'for some reason'. It is always better to have the database define its own unique keys if possible.

Comment: If I were you, I would save the trouble and just turn on auto-increment. But yes, it should be safe.

Answer (score 3):

It really shouldn't make any difference where the UUIDs are generated, as long as they are unique.  There isn't anything special about MySQL's built-in `UUID()` function.

The problem, however, is with UUIDs in general.  In InnoDB (which is what you *should* be using), the primary key is the clustered index... which means rows are physically stored in primary key order... which means you have a performance penalty to consider any time rows are not inserted into a table in primary key order.  You will have a significant number of page splits and a significant amount of fragmentation in your tables.

And, clearly, if you generate several UUIDs in succession, it should be readily apparent that they are not lexically sequential.

Additionally, and particularly if you store a UUID as a 36-character `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` then your joins will be on 36-byte values, which brings its own potential performance issues -- in contrast with an `INT`, which is only 4 bytes, or a `BIGINT`, which is 8.  Foreign key constraint checking will also have to use larger values.

An `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key solves both issues, because rows are, by definition, inserted in primary key order, and the keys are comprised of fewer bytes, which should mean better join performance.

Will the performance be horrible?  No, but it won't be optimal.

However, to answer the question, it should not matter how or where the UUIDs are generated.  One of the motivations, in fact, for UUIDs, is the very fact that they should be unique, regardless of source.

Comment: Thanks to whoever, for the drive-by down-vote without an explanation.  That's "helpful."